# Quelle est la différence entre « coordinateur » et « coordonnateur » ?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, choix-de-mot, travail

Dans un contexte administratif, j'ai commis l'erreur d'utiliser le terme « coordinateur » mais le bon sens était « coordonnateur ».

Quelle est la différence entre les deux ?

Comment: Je suis un peu surpris par la réponse acceptée qui se base sur une seule source qui contient plusieurs affirmations discutables. Coordinateur n'est pas plus (et pas moins) un néologisme que coordinateur, ces deux mots sont à priori apparus à une trentaine d'années d'intervalle, rien ne permet d'affirmer que coordinateur vient de l'anglais, il n'est pas en concurrence avec coordinateur depuis la moitié du XXe siècle mais depuis son apparition une centaine d'années plus tôt. Il n'y a pas de consensus pour recommander l'utilisation de l'un plutôt que l'autre.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coordonnateur et coordinateur sont des synonymes, mais coordinateur vient de l'anglais. L'utilisation du mot "coordonnateur" est recommandé.

> Pour désigner la personne qui a la charge de coordonner diverses initiatives ou actions, de mettre bon ordre dans des éléments
>   dispersés, le substantif coordonnateur (avec deux n) a été
>   régulièrement formé sur le verbe coordonner, tout comme ordonnateur
>   l'est sur ordonner. Il peut s'employer adjectivement.
>
> Je vous présente la coordonnatrice du projet.
>
> Un esprit coordonnateur.
>
> Depuis le milieu du XXe siècle, ce terme est concurrencé par le
>   néologisme coordinateur (avec un seul n), formé sur coordination ou
>   emprunté de l'anglais coordinator, et de même sens : « personne qui
>   coordonne diverses initiatives ou actions, qui met de l'ordre dans des
>   éléments dispersés. »
>
> Hanse recommande le premier mais reconnaît le second. On se gardera
>   surtout de toute confusion orthographique (coordinnation, coordonateur
>   et autres barbarismes relevés sur la Toile), sous l'effet d'une
>   mauvaise coordination mentale (et non coordonnation).
>
> http://parler-francais.eklablog.com/coordonnateur-coordinateur-a31284699

Answer (score 11):

Selon [Larousse](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/coordonnateur_coordonnatrice/19072/difficulte)

> Les deux formes sont correctes. Coordinateur est d'emploi courant alors que coordonnateur est d'usage administratif ou technique.

C'est surtout une différence d'usage.

Comment: Pourquoi cette différence d'usage ?

Comment: Parce que dans le milieu administratif on aime à utiliser des mots compliqués qui font le buzz pour avoir l'air à la mode. Comme n'importe qui utilise "coordinateur" on lui préfère le plus mystérieux "coordonnateur" que le pékin moyen n'utilise pas.

Answer (score 10):

LE TFLI indique dans l'entrée [coordinateur/coordonnateur](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/coordinateur):

> Une distinction semble actuellement se dessiner, et l'opinion publique
>   donne à coordonnateur un sens plus fort qu'à son concurrent. ,,Il est
>   probable qu'un glissement de sens va s'opérer. Sous l'influence d'«
>   ordonner » qui signifie « mettre en ordre » mais aussi « donner des
>   ordres », le mot « coordonnateur » prendra la valeur suivante : «
>   personnage chargé d'assurer avec énergie et autorité la mise en ordre
>   − en bon ordre − d'éléments qui, sans lui, agiraient en ordre dispersé
>   et de façon peu cohérente ». Je parie donc pour le succès de «
>   coordonnateur ».`` (A. Guillermou ds Carrefour, 29 avril 1976, p. 13).

Google ngram montre d'une part que ces deux mots sont très peu fréquents et d'autre part que *coordinateur*, apparu une trentaine d'années après *coordonnateur*, est plus utilisé que ce dernier depuis le milieu du XIXe siècle.

[image]

Comment: Si besoin est, pour confirmer que la réponse de jiliagre est la bonne, je signale la [chronique récente](http://www.tv5monde.com/cms/chaine-francophone/lf/Merci-Professeur/p-17081-Coordonateur-et-coordinateur.htm?episode=619) (beaucoup plus récente que 1976) de [Bernard Cerquiglini](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernard_Cerquiglini) qui confirme le dessus pris par « coordonnateur » dans le langage administratif.

Answer (score 4):

Il est dit que la distinction entre les deux, bien que très ambiguë, se situe au niveau de sens du verbe « Coordonner ». (soit arranger, disposer des choses convenablement. soit organiser, synchroniser des actions).

Dans le cas du coordOnnateur, il pencherait plus vers le côté « arrangement ». Un coordonnateur : arrange, dispose et remet de l'ordre dans les éléments « désorganisés » (cela peut être des objets ou des idées).

Dans le cas du coordInateur, il serait plus du côté de l'organisation et la synchronisation. Un coordinateur : organise et planifie des choses.

Selon moi, la différence se situe sur le fait que l'un a une tendance à agir sur l'organisation *d'objets* (physiques ou non) => Coordonnateur. 
Et l'autre agit sur l'organisation *d'actions* (encadrer des individus par exemple, on parle de coordinateur ou organisateur).

Answer (score 3):

*Coordonnateur* et *coordinateur* sont synonymes et représentent un agent qui coordonne une action dans un groupe.

Dans l'aviation "un agent chargé d'établir l'occupation des aires de trafic", est un coordonnateur, mais les deux mots sont employés indifféremment dans les offres d'emploi pour les autres activités.

Answer (score 3):

Coordonnateur et Coordinateur sont deux mots synonymes, d'où le choix de l'emploi de l'un ou de l'autre dépend simplement de la personne qui veut l'employer et du contexte dans lequel elle veut l'insérer mais actuellement une légère supériorité est accordée à Coordonnateur du fait que dans ce même mot, il y a la présence de deux verbes à la fois: Coordonner et Ordonner pendant que son concurrent,  Coordinateur vient du mot anglais "Coordinator" et du verbe "to coordinate". Cependant, on n'y retrouve que le verbe Coordonner seulement.

Answer (score 3):

Le Bureau de la traduction du Canada (via Termium) semble préconiser l'usage du substantif "coordonnateur" en ce qui a trait aux personnes plutôt que "coordinateur", qu'on recommande à être utilisé plutôt sous une forme adjectivale (une mesure coordinatrice).